# Is a circle a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology

Intuitively, I think that a circle is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But, how I can prove this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Show that its complement is open.

Answer (score 6):

It is the zero-locus of the continuous function $(x,y) \mapsto x^2+y^2-1 : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, and $\{0\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, so $\{ (x,y) \mid x^2+y^2-1 \}$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

We need to be careful with terminology. Centre on the origin and set the radius to $1$. The *open disk* is $r<1$; the *closed disk* is $r\ge 1$; the *circle* is $r=1$. As you can probably guess from the name (and can easily prove yourself), the first of these is open not closed, while the latter is the reverse. As for the circle, it's not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, although it is closed because $r\ne 1$ is also open.